# Mupub ads work in emulator, but not in release build

Tags: android, mopub, android-proguard

Installed the Mopub SDK into my Android Studio project (via Fabric), and get full screen ads to work when running in the emulator.

However, once I generate a signed ADK build and distribute to real devices, the ads don't appear.

Could this be related to ProGuard? Does minifyEnabled need to be true?

Comment: Any errors in logcat?

Comment: No because the ads just don't show after being released via a signed ADK so I'm not sure how to debug it